# Force an activity to remain in memory

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine, in-app-billing

I have implemented in app billing in a game. We are using unity3d as our game development engine . For in app billing to work I wrote a java native plugin that handles in app billing jobs and send messages back to unity application when purchase is done.
The way I implemented this is to start another activity to handle billing tasks and finish that activity after the tasks are done to return to unity app. But the problem is that in some devices(specially with low RAM) the unity app get closed when the billing activity is started . So when the user purchase an item our listeners in unity app are no longer valid and the unity app is restarted. We can't give them the item which is bought (It's consumed).

So my question is that is there any way to force the unity app remain untouched while the billing activity is running ?

My Code that fires billing activity:

```
public static void Buy(String SKU,String developerPayLoad,boolean Consumable)
{
    Intent buyIntent = new Intent(gameActivity,MyketActivity.class);
    buyIntent.putExtra("OPERATION", "PURCHASE");
    buyIntent.putExtra("SKU", SKU);
    buyIntent.putExtra("PayLoad", developerPayLoad);
    buyIntent.putExtra("Consumable", Consumable);

    gameActivity.startActivityForResult(buyIntent, 8586);

}


//The billing activity's OnCreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    String Operation = getIntent().getStringExtra("OPERATION");
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    if(!FirstTime)
    {
        MyketHelper.Log("Not for the First Time");
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if(Operation.equals("PURCHASE"))
    {
        if(MyketHelper.helper==null)
        {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        MyketHelper.Log("Purchase Flow Launched");
        SKU = getIntent().getStringExtra("SKU");
        PayLoad = getIntent().getStringExtra("PayLoad");
        Consumeable = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Consumable", true);

        MyketHelper.helper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU, 8585, OnPurchase);

    }


}
```

Comment: No, this is of course not permitted to unprivileged applications, as it would be abused (intentionally or cluelessly) and result in denial of service.  Typically the only ordinary app so protected is the launcher (by its selection as such), and even that only sometimes.

Comment: Thanks. So what is my option in this situation?

Comment: Redesign your program to not require this - store information persistently so that it work even if you come back to a new instance.